# How can I compare a nullable type date using user entered date?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, entity-framework-6

I can't find how to compare a date entered by a user to a date on a table created by EF6. I'm using LINQ Extensions to search the DB and have tried multiple suggestions that compile, but fail during execution.

**User Input:**

```
DateTime userdate;
DateTime.TryParse(search.Value, out userdate);
```

**Attempts so far:**

```
a = dbContext.Messages.Where(x => x.Date.Date == userdate.Date); // doesn't compile
a = dbContext.Messages.Where(x => x.Date.Value.Date == userdate.Date); // error # 4
a = dbContext.Messages.Where(x => x.Date.ToString() == userdate.Date.ToString()); // issue #2
a = dbContext.Messages.Where(x => x.Date.Value.ToString() == userdate.Date.ToString()); // issue #2
a = dbContext.Messages.Where(x => Object.Equals(x.Date, userdate.Date)); // throws error #1
a = dbContext.Messages.Where(x => Object.Equals(x.Date.Date, userdate.Date)); // throws error #1
```

I've tried searching this a million times and find solutions that compile, yet always throw an error when executed.

There was a version of the `ToString()` that worked, but it generated a long date string such as `May 12, 2005 00:00:00` and trying to turn my userdate into a long date to compare just seems like it would create too much overhead when searching through millions of records.

I'm fresh out of ideas here.

Issues:

1. > Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable``1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
2. Doesn't find any matches, even with exact datetime
3. Magically works all of a sudden.
4. > The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

**Final solution**
Based on the selected answer, I found that the SqlFunctions class has a .DateDiff method which maps to the T-SQL DateDiff function. I used that to count the number of days between the two dates and selected only the ones that returned 0. That allowed me to compare the dates without having to do any conversion on the SQL side.

Comment: So you say there's an error... *what error is it*?

Comment: (It's odd to use `Where` directly on a `dbContext` rather than on a table within the context, btw...)

Comment: If the database value is nullable, why isn't the user input value nullable?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'm trying to recreate the error now to post... and thanks for pointing that out, I tried to shorten the code and took off too much. Updated question with correct code.

Comment: @David, I think TryParse always returns a value, so I thought it would save resources by not declaring it nullable.

Comment: I made a mistake when writing out the question. Originally, I had x.Date.Value.Date for the second attempt, but in my code it was x.Date.Date.Value, which didn't compile.

Comment: @dageniusal The reason for errors 1 and 4 is what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I updated the question to include what I ended up doing in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some .NET operations can not be implicitly converted to equivalent SQL operations, for these you need to use the methods provided in  [System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). In your specific example, you should try using the `TruncateTime` method instead of accessing `.Date` property of the `DateTime` instance.

Example:

```
var date = userDate.Date;
dbSet.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == date);
```

Edit: Alternatively, the SQL server does not necessarily support the same range for `datetime`-values as .NET does, so if your string parse fails and you get `DateTime.MinValue` it may not be a supported `datetime` value in your SQL server.

Comment: So I looked at the documentation for System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions and found class SqlFunctions. It has many of the functions I use a lot when writing T-SQL, which helps me make the transition from .NET code to T-SQL.

Using that, I tried 

`dbSet.Where(x => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Day", x.Date.Value, userdate) == 0);`

.. and it worked. 

Question now, since I know that this works as well

`.Where(x => x.Date.Value == userdate.Date)`

Are there any performance differences?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using the function listed above. I found that it didn't require any converting on the SQL side, which should improve performance.